# Rendering the same image without using Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, turtle-graphics

I have found this [code](https://www.101computing.net/moroccan-mosaic/) for combining polygons into Mosaics. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191039/python-turtle-speed) it seems that turtle will only go so fast. I don't need the hand drawing and would just like to see the images rendered. Of course, not using turtle, I would have to use something else (I am hoping to use PIL). So the problems are two fold:

1. How can I still get the up and left movements that seem to draw the mosaic without using Turtle.
2. How can I use PIL as the image display platform?

It seems however that it is through `myPen.left()` and `myPen.forward()` that the drawing happens:

```
import turtle
myPen = turtle.Turtle()
myPen.shape("arrow")

myPen.speed(1000)
def drawMosaic(color,numberOfSides,size,numberOfIterations):
 myPen.color(color)
 for i in range(0,numberOfIterations):
   for j in range (0,numberOfSides):
     myPen.forward(size)
     myPen.left(360 / numberOfSides)
   myPen.left(360 / numberOfIterations)

drawMosaic("#0B5CCB",8,40,10)
myPen.hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need the hand drawing and would just like to see the images
>   rendered.

You can achieve this within turtle.  If you don't care about the animation of the drawing process, you can use the `tracer()` method to turn it off:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawMosaic(color, numberOfSides, size, numberOfIterations):
    myPen.color(color)

    for _ in range(numberOfIterations):
        for _ in range(numberOfSides):
            myPen.forward(size)
            myPen.left(360 / numberOfSides)

        myPen.left(360 / numberOfIterations)

screen = Screen()

myPen = Turtle(visible=False)

screen.tracer(False)
drawMosaic("#0B5CCB", 8, 40, 10)
screen.tracer(True)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Make sure to turn `tracer()` back on after you're done drawing to avoid certain artifacts (like a broken `hideturtle()`, etc.)

Comment: Much easier than I thought. Thanks for this.