# How do I make a turtle run faster?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Here's some basic code, how do I make it run faster?

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()

sasha = turtle.Turtle()

length = 12
for i in range(65):
    sasha.forward(length)
    sasha.right(120)
    length = length + 10
```

Comment: How about `length = length + 11`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191039/python-turtle-speed)

Comment: @goodvibration, your answer is incorrect because length is used for moving forward. so `length = length + 11` will just add one step forward. It has nothing to do with speed.

Comment: @aspasha I have answered you question. And I have explained to you how to use the speed function. The link provided by Uli Sotschok is also good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up python's 'turtle' function and stop it freezing at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119991/how-to-speed-up-pythons-turtle-function-and-stop-it-freezing-at-the-end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `speed()` to change turtle's speed - like in other answer - but you can also turn off animation

```
 turtle.tracer(False)
```

and you will have to manually inform turtle when it has to update content on screen

```
 turtle.update()
```

This way you can get all at once - without delay

```
import turtle

turtle.tracer(False) # stop animation and don't update content on screen

wn = turtle.Screen()
sasha = turtle.Turtle()

length = 12
for i in range(65):
    sasha.forward(length)
    sasha.right(120)
    length = length + 10

turtle.update() # update content on screen

turtle.done()
```

---

Doc: [turtle.tracer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer), [turtle.update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.update)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `speed()` function 
The more you increase the more you increase the value the more it is slow.

- “fastest”: 0
- “fast”: 10
- “normal”: 6
- “slow”: 3
- “slowest”: 1

You can use it like this `sasha.speed(0`) for example.

> Note: `speed(0)` is the most fast coz the pen will not draw.

check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.speed) for more info